# register_rest_field update_callback not work

Tags: wordpress, api, wp-api

I’m trying to update a custom field, but when I run the route through POSTMAN it does not update the field. Creates a new record. The route is something like:
$POST …wp/v2/posts/362/meta?key=servicos_status&value=pause

Someone help me?
[code print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lvCl.png)

Comment: have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that in the update callback you're receiving an Object or an array. My callbacks look like this:

```
function slugGetPostMetaCb($object, $field_name, $request) {
    return get_post_meta($object['id'], $field_name, true);
}

function slugUpdatePostMetaCb($value, $object, $field_name) {
    return update_post_meta($object['id'], $field_name, $value);
}
```